# How can i integrate cisco webex api in my application to display video which is stored in the cisco server?

Tags: android, rest, api

This my json data ,this link directs to another tab in website and plays video and now i have to integrate in my android application .
now how can i play this video? help me to find out this answer?

```
{
 "topic": "topic",
 "date": "2017-11-10",
 "link": "https://videolink",
 "password": "bksbbggg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ability to play WebEx recordings may depend on the type of recordings stored on the WebEx site.

Recordings created locally are generally in .WRF (proprietary to WebEx) format, and I'm not sure they can be played on mobile devices. For these to exist on your WebEx site, the host must have manually uploaded them.

Other types of WebEx recordings would be .ARF (also proprietary, but specific to Network Based Recordings, aka NBR) and more recently .MP4, which is obviously a non-proprietary standard and the most likely format to work in your application. .WRF and .ARF files should be convertible to .WMV, .MP4, and Flash using the conversion tool that is part of the player offered by WebEx (see https://help.webex.com/docs/DOC-10502 for more info).

I would suggest checking out the NBR API documentation at https://developer.cisco.com/site/webex-developer/develop-test/nbr-web-services-api/ for information on how to pull these recording files (should you decide to host them on your servers) as well as the XML API LstRecording (https://d1nmyq4gcgsfi5.cloudfront.net/site/webex-developer/develop-test/xml-api/xml-api-reference/#lstrecording - Link subject to change - if it does, visit webexdeveloper.com -> Develop and Test -> XML API -> XML API Reference) which will return any available details about recordings stored on your WebEx site.